# Find alphabetic words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to write function, that check if word is alphabetical, for example

```
my_function('Hello!')
>> True
my_function('How')
>> True
my_function('F!@K')
>> False
my_function('</html>')
>> False
```

I have no idea. I really bad in `re` lib.

```
begin_searcher = re.compile(r'[\w\-]')
end_searcher = re.compile(r'[\w\-]+[!-?]')
```

I can't use non-standard libs

Comment: -1. This question shows no effort to attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Why is `Hello!` "alphabetical" but `</html>` is not?

Comment: Because any word with `?` and `!` on end is alphabetical

Comment: Can you elaborate on your definition of 'alphabetical'? It can end with ? or !, but what else? Can it have several punctuations, or other ones ('a!!!', 'oh.'...)? can it have spaces or punctuation inside? ...

Comment: No spaces or punctuation inside, can end with ',.!?' with some combination like `'!!!!??' , '?!' , '.....' , '.', ','`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non regex solution

```
from string import ascii_letters
def foo(st):
    letters = ascii_letters
    letters_nd_term = letters + "?!"
    return not any([set(st[:-1]).difference(letters),st[-1] not in letters_nd_term])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a better job at defining what a "word" is. If ! and ? are ok on the end of a word, what about . and , and ; and :, etc?

Here is something that may do the trick:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+[.,!?]?')
>>> m = pat.match(word) #where word is what you're checking
>>> True if m else False
```

Of course this doesn't account for a word wrapped in quotes, or multiple punctuation at the end of the word, or all the types of punctuation. But it should give you a good place to start while you work out what a "word" is.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use sets rather than a regexp for this:

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
>>> def is_alpha(word):
    return set(word).issubset(letters)

>>> for wrd in 'Hello! Hello How F!@K </html>'.split():
    print("is_alpha(%r) == %r" % (wrd, is_alpha(wrd)))


is_alpha('Hello!') == False
is_alpha('Hello') == True
is_alpha('How') == True
is_alpha('F!@K') == False
is_alpha('</html>') == False
>>>
```